# Upload Image browser widget for drupal 6

Tags: 6, media

I need the following combined options, to browse and choose images from **previous uploads** (or) upload new image from **hard drive**. Currently I configured with default upload widget(file->Image), so I can choose image from hard drive only, but I don't want to upload the same(duplicate) image again and also it will save lot of space. I want to avoid same image upload, Is any module available with both options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [FileField Sources](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module

> FileField Sources is an extension to the FileField module. The
>   FileField module lets you upload files from your computer through a
>   CCK field. The FileField Sources module expands on this ability by
>   allowing you to select new or existing files through additional means,
>   including:
>
> 1. Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
> 2. Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
> 3. Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
> 4. Paste a file directly from the clipboard (Drupal 7 only)
> 5. Select existing files through the IMCE file browser

[image]
the first one is what youre looking for.